# POST JSON with Flurl

Tags: c#, json, post, json.net, flurl

I start with Flurl and I would like to create a POST but I think I have a problem with the format of my JSON parameters.

You can see the JSON parameters:

```
{
    "aaaUser" : {
    "attributes" : {
        "name" : "device:domain\\login",
        "pwd" : "123456"
        }
    }
}
```

These settings work with Postman and now I would like to use Flurl to continue my little POST :) But my JSON format is not correct.

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Flurl.Http;

namespace Script
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var result = await "https://IP/api/aaaLogin.json".PostUrlEncodedAsync(new
            {
                name = "device:domain\\login",
                pwd = "123456"
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Your actual code isn't posting JSON. That's not what UrlEncodedAsync is for. UrlEncodedAsync is for POSTing like from an HTML form. Read [the documentation](https://flurl.io/docs/fluent-http/). It clearly shows how to PostJsonAsync.

Comment: @mason Yes exactly now I can use PostJsonAsync. However the problem with JSON format is always present. Because I need to make a first connection.

Comment: What do you mean you need to make a first connection? What is the exact error you're getting? Please take some time to think about how other people are going to view your question. Remember, we're not at your computer. We can't see what you're doing. It's up to you to properly convey the information to us in a way we can understand.

Comment: @mason Ok I am sorry for that.
Currently I used Postman to make diffrent action (POST -> for the first connection on my device and after that I can execute different GET action).
If you see my first message I introduced the JSON used in Postman and he works correctly.
So now I would like to use Flurl to make the same action. However I think the problem is my JSON paramter in my script because when I run this one I receive: {"totalCount":"1","imdata":[{"error":{"attributes":{"code":"400","text":"Failed to parse login request"}}}]}.

If you need more information do not hesitate !

Comment: What API are you working with here? Does it have documentation?

Comment: ACI from CISCO and this error is present when you do not send what is requested. I know this API I worked with ansible and he works correctly.
We need to specify this parameters ` {
    "aaaUser" : {
    "attributes" : {
        "name" : "device:domain\\login",
        "pwd" : "123456"
        }
    }
}`
And not only user and pwd. But I don't know the format in my C# script.

Comment: Define your JSON object to post. Create a class structure that when serialized will result in the correct JSON. Your object you're making now is a single object with two string properties. That doesn't match the JSON shown at the top of your question. Your question doesn't seem to be about Flurl, just about basic JSON serialization.

Comment: Yes exactly but I can not put the JSON correctly in this script.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think 2 problems have been identified here.

1. You're using `PostUrlEncodedAsync`, which is going to send the data in URL-encoded format, like this: `name=device:domain\\login&pwd=123456`. If you want the data serialized to JSON, use `PostJsonAsync` instead.
2. You're only including the nested `attributes` object of the JSON and not the entire object.

In short, you're going to want something like this:

```
var result = await "https://IP/api/aaaLogin.json".PostJsonAsync(new
{
    aaaUser = new
    {
        attributes = new
        {
            name = "device:domain\\login",
            pwd = "123456"
        }
    }
});
```

Once you get this far, you're going to need to know how to process the results. If the response is JSON formatted, you'll likely want to append `.ReceiveJson()` or `.ReceiveJson<T>()` to the above call in order to have a more friendly object to work with. Please refer to the [documentation](https://flurl.io/docs/fluent-http/).

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. It's really clear and my problem is solved.
I will deepen Flurl :)